# What favicon size does iPhone's "Add to Favorites" need?

Tags: html, jekyll, favicon, mobile-website

I'm following Apple's [Safari Web Content Guide - Configuring Web Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) and it works as expected most of the time. But when I want to add to favorites on iPhone, the favicon doesn't show up. Is it the size issue? Or what else should I do for the favorites icon to show up? Thanks

[image]

---

My Code:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon/" href="{{ "/favicon.ico" | relative_url }}">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ "/apple-touch-icon.png" | relative_url }}">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="{{ "/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" | relative_url }}">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="{{ "/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" | relative_url }}">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="{{ "/touch-icon-ipad.png" | relative_url }}">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{{ "/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png" | relative_url }}">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="{{ "/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png" | relative_url }}">
  {%- seo -%}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/main.css" | relative_url }}">
  {%- feed_meta -%}
  {%- if jekyll.environment == 'production' and site.google_analytics -%}
    {%- include google-analytics.html -%}
  {%- endif -%}
  <!-- site css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{'/assets/main.css' | prepend: site.baseurl}}">
  {% seo %}
</head>
```

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question directly but you might consider a generator that gets everything you need all at once: https://realfavicongenerator.net/

Comment: @Charlie Wow that's a genius idea. Thank you so much for the link. I will definitely try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out and it is displaying the favicons properly now. Thanks a lot, @Charlie, for the favicon checker website: https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker#.YIHdji1h0Ts

It seemed like I messed up some favicon resolutions, so they caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
```

Per Apple’s current guidance, default touch icon sizes are as follows:
[image]

Comment: I'm so sorry that I forgot to include the current code I have. I actually included them in my code. It works for tab favicons, and "add to home" on iPhone. However, "add to favorites" doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you include the source for this for future people coming here can have the most updated sizes per Apple's guidelines? I see this being very helpful for developers